# Make the interaction with c++

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I wrote a small program in c ++ (cli) which allows to launch a request on a site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>


static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/?id=1&hash=123456");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code works very well and fulfills the task I ask

I would need to create an interactive version to modify the variables of the url.
Example of output of the program:

```
./my_prog
What content do you want to add in the variable id?
1
What content do you want to add in the hash variable?
123456879
```

And after these questions, it will launch the CURL query with the results of the questions.
Could you explain can i do the interaction with c++?

Comment: _"Could you explain can i do the interaction with c++?"_ Use `std::cin`?

Comment: @user0042 exactly! :D thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to console, use `std::cout << "something"` to get input, use `std::cin >> x;`

in your example it would look like this:

```
std::string id, hash;
std::cout << "What content do you want to add in the variable id?\n";
std::cin >> id;
std::cout << "What content do you want to add in the hash variable?\n";
std::cin >> hash;
```

to insert new data into url, replace this one line:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/?id=" + id + "&hash=" + hash);
```

`std::cin` will read input until first whitespace or endline character, if for some reasons you need to enter several words, you can use `getline (std::cin, hash);` it will read full line

Comment: The problem of the OP might be that they'll need to extract first what parameters should be filled in from that particular URL. I believe that they are already aware how to communicate via `std::cin`.

Comment: I will update the answer if that's the case. "interaction with c++" is hard to understand, maybe question owner will elaborate on that

Comment: You should probably not write an answer until the question isn't clear at all. That's what comments are for. Not that hard to get the missing 20 rep to allow you commenting everywhere.